# Rails - CSV (export to csv)

Tags: csv

i am exporting data to csv,

while exporting i want to split by every 50 records, instead of exporting all together.

(i.e, if i click "Export to CSV" it should export first 50 records, later again on clicking "Export to csv" it should export next 50 records and so on)

please, provide me some code to solve this problem.

thanks

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360682/rails-csvexport-to-csv-loop/1361155#1361155

Comment: how many times can you ask this damned question, bloody hell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pagination is not required you could try [`AR#find_in_batches`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods.html#M001846).

```
Record.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 50) do |records|
  export_to_csv(records) # max 50 records
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
records = ModelClass.find(:limit => 50, ...)
# convert records to CSV

# later:
records = ModelClass.find(:limit => 50, :offset => 50, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want pagination (you do a 50 record per page).

There's a plugin for that: [`will_paginate`](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/master)

Then you do: `Model.paginate :page` => `params[:page]`, `:per_page` => `50`

Then just add 1 to your page every time.