# CSV-Export problem in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

for Export to CSV, i have overall 2500 records, and while exporting it
takes long time to export all records, so, i have decided to export in
the form of  1st 50 students,and, 2nd 50 students,so on.  I have tried
the below code. but it could able to fetch only 1st 50 students.
please, guide me how to solve the problem

```
def exportcsv

  @student_count = Student.find(:all)

  @count1 = @student_count.count

  st_per_file = 50

  count = 0

  unless @count1==count

  students = Student.find(:all, :order => 'name', :limit =>
               st_per_file, :offset => (st_per_file*count))

  count = count + 1


 filename = 'students.csv'

  headers.merge!(

    'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',

    'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\"",

    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary'
  )
 --------------
 --------------
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Didn't we just [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360682/rails-csvexport-to-csv-loop/1361155#1361155) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360682/rails-csvexport-to-csv-loop) yesterday? I don't really see what has changed between the two other than there is more code now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, theIV. Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

2500 records isn't very much, this smells in my opinion. Sounds like you should be sorting out why this is so bad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a loop to do this. Ruby's 'unless' keyword is a negated if and only runs once. Try a 'while' or an 'until'.